# How to play an Animation with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, onmouseover

Im coding a fade-in and fade-out text on button hover... and I have to call an animation onhover... how I can do it?

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const disp_text = document.getElementById('disp_text');

button.onmouseover = function(){
 //Here goes the animation to play
 disp_text.innerText = "Next";
}
```

I've Tried:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const disp_text = document.getElementById('disp_text');

button.onmouseover = function(){
 animation.Play("fadein");
 disp_text.innerText = "Next";
}
```

But nothing...

If someone can help, I would be very grateful...

Comment: Where does this come from: ```animation.Play("fadein");```? Is text changing on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.play()` will only work if you have mentioned how to `animate`

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const disp_text = document.getElementById('disp_text');

button.onmouseover = function(){
 disp_text.innerText = "Next";
 
 const animation = disp_text.animate(
[
  { opacity: 0 },
  { opacity: 1 }
], {
  easing: 'ease',
  duration: 2000
});

 animation.play();
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Hello</button>
<p id="disp_text"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that uses javascript to animate a fade when the button is hovered. I've also implemented a pure css version. I was about to implement a version using the Animate API but I see that @DEEPAK has done that, so that's a third option.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const disp_text = document.getElementById('disp_text');


button.onmouseover = function(){
  disp_text.classList.add('button-hover');
}

button.onmouseout = function(){
  disp_text.classList.remove('button-hover');
}
```

```css
#disp_text {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
#disp_text.button-hover {
  opacity:1;
}

#disp_text2 {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
#btn2:hover #disp_text2 {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Hover over this to see the animation of the DIV below</button>
<p id='disp_text'>Next</p>

<p>The one below uses css only - no javascript. This is easy because the span is inside the button</p>
<button id='btn2'><span id='disp_text2'>Next</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "animation.fadeIn". There is, to my knowledge, no object named "animation" in vanilla JS.

A way to code a fade-in and fade-out animation is to use the CSS property opacity.

If you were to code this animation in CSS, you could do:

```
#btn {opacity: 0.5; }
#btn:hover {opacity: 1}
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.